# Unable to install Ubuntu on Toshiba Sattelite after download interrupted

Tags: installation, boot, laptop, windows-vista

While trying to replace vista on my laptop with Ubuntu via a boot disk, someone unplugged the computer and the installation was interrupted. I tried shutting down the PC and restarting, but found that not only was the PC giving me the "no OS" screen, but refused to load any Ubuntu disks.

Is there anything I can do to re-install Ubuntu?

Comment: Repeat the whole process again.

Comment: You mean it won't let you boot from CD?

Answer (score 0):

Set your boot device priority to CD/USB (whatever your bootable Ubuntu media is) instead of HDD form the Boot menu.

Comment: And how do I do this?

Comment: When you switch on your computer, press F12. Then select the bootable media source.